# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module. Did you install mysqlclient?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mysql-python, python-3.7

```
(py5) C:\Users\NIKITA GULHANE\projects\ganesh>python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x00000282C396CA60>
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 15, in <module> import MySQLdb as Database ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception raise _exception[1]

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate app_config.import_models()

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 726, in exec_module

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

File"C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\sitepackages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

File"C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\sitepackages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 114, in __new__ new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 315, in add_to_class value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__ return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__ backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "C:\Users\NIKITA~1\Envs\py5\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
```

Did you install mysqlclient?

Comment: i am using window 10. and when i run the server then this error is occure help me anyone please... Thank you in advance

Comment: As the last line of the error suggests, you need to install mysqlclient: `pip install mysqlclient`.

Comment: if i go for the installation then also give me the error

Comment: this error is giving me.

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: python 3.7 is using

Comment: Please edit the question to show the error from `pip install mysqlclient` - it will be more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error from Django, you need to install `mysqlclient`.

Python 3.7 hasn't been released yet, so you'll have to compile `mysqlclient` from source.

It would be much easier to use Python 3.6.x, then `pip install mysqlclient` will install the wheel.